# Sending data from Spigot server to Fabric client

Tags: minecraft, spigot, minecraft-fabric

I wanna send data from server to client using pluginMessage.
using this code on the server

```
public static void sendPmcAdd(Player player, RegionContainer container) {
        if(!player.hasPermission(ClientModPermission))
            return;

        ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
        out.write(0);
        out.writeUTF("add");

        container.serialize(out,true);

        player.sendPluginMessage(MineBreak.getInstance(), "mb:region", out.toByteArray());
    }
```

line:
`container.serialize(out,true);`
adds position data of the region.

on the client i read the recived message like this

```
private void handlePacket(@NotNull MinecraftClient client, @NotNull ClientPlayNetworkHandler handler,
                              @NotNull PacketByteBuf buffer, @NotNull PacketSender sender) {
        String message = buffer.readString();
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

but the message is empty. how should i read the data on the client, or am i doing something wrong on the server?

Client is 1.20.1 fabric
Server is 1.17.1 with ViaVersion plugin so other then 1.17.1 versions of the game can connect

I tried sending just simple string like "test message" to test if there is something wrong with region adding data. but its still empty on the client.

Comment: Don't know much about plugin messaging with mods. I've used something like that with the normal PluginMessaging channel used by BungeeCord and Velocity. I wish I could help, but again, I don't know much about that kind of stuff. One time I had a problem with the messaging channel because I tried to read it directly and didn't save my data as a variable. Maybe check that out?

Comment: Did you tried to read the number first then after read the string?